# With Flyback Diode, still have spike.

Tags: diodes, flyback, induction

[image: Circuit]

I have the above circuit on a breadboard, where my PWM is coming form a microcontroller with its own current limited power supply. the motor is being powered from another output of my power supply. So I have added this diode 15SQ045 
which i sourced from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CXOQMJ8), despite the fact it said "for solar cells" I was satisfied with the "shottky" property.

Anyways the issue is that without the diode I get voltage spikes of about 128V and with the diode those come down to about 38V. My question is why are the spikes still so high? Can i improve it?

I have tried adding more diodes in parallel but that does nothing.

Comment: How are you measuring the spike voltages?

Comment: I am using an oscilloscope

Comment: Of course you're using an oscilloscope but how do you measure? Please look at [this](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-02-43/1738.scope_5F00_probes_5F00_gnd_5F00_wire.jpg) image and answer again.

Comment: the motor does not have a capacitor in parallel with it.. could this be the issue? I am just probing directly on the motor leads

Comment: All mosfets used in switch mode need a 10 ohm to 33 ohm resistor at the gate to prevent ringing and overshoot. Look up 'snubber' capacitor/resistor combo's and put that across the motor. A capacitor alone may cause the mosfet to overheat.

Comment: thanks for the info guys! I was probing it all wrong!!! I was probing the low side of the motor with respect to ground on my breadboard instead of across the motor. Now i get what I expected. And I added a capacitor. Now I need to research about those resistors at the gate because I assumed since it is a field effect device  resistors at the gate were not needed

Comment: @Eddiea6987 You were probing it correct. Of course you should probe the low-side of the motor w.r.t. GND (i.e. across the D and S of the MOSFET) because the spikes are dangerous for the MOSFET!

Comment: Well in that case I am back at square 1 since  I am still getting 40V+ spikes when measured across the Drain and Source, where it matters  versus closer to the motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surely depends on how it is measured. The following 2 images from TI are quite helpful on measuring noise/ringing signals:

[image: The TERRIBLE way]

[image: The better way]

These images represent how to "probe". Note that a long ground cable of the probe can pick up a lot of noise from outside.

---

There are also some other things to consider:

**- Insufficiently Bypassed Supply Line:** It's also quite important to bypass the supply line at higher frequencies. I would put 1-100nF capacitor(s) across the supply line as close to the point where the motor is supplied as possible.

**- Stray inductances:** Sad but true. Although it's hard to say without seeing the setup there should be some stray inductances coming from the setup/layout. The tracks/cables from positive supply line to motor, from motor to mosfet, from mosfet to ground, from motor to diode's anode, from diode's cathode to motor etc. All create some stray inductances. So, keep those tracks/cables short as possible.

**- Bad/insufficient/weak gate drive:** Sorry but schematic does not show anything about this. If the gate has a series resistor then put a fast diode (e.g. 4148) parallel to this resistor in a way that the anode is connected to the gate and the cathode is connected to the PWM source. This helps to turn the MOSFET off faster.

**- Capacitor Across the Motor:** Try putting a lower than or equal to 1nF ceramic capacitor right across the leads of the motor.

**- dv/dt of the Diode:** I'm not sure about this but I think other experts may enlighten.

If there are spikes after fixing/improving these issues then put a snubber across the drain and source of the MOSFET. [This](http://www.cde.com/resources/technical-papers/design.pdf) document is quite helpful on designing snubbers.

Comment: thanks for this I will definitely print out that app note, should be a good read!